# Interview task about how to design program, which will work with big data

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns

I had interview yesterday, and I had such question - there is **server** and **database**, which store **big text** information(every text can be >10 Mb). Any query to database is **expensive**. You need to design a program(server) which will take a text and say - is this text in database or not.

I request such decision - 
Make a good **hash** of every text. Then make a **set** of all hashes. If hash of input text **is not in set** - so there is no such text, else - go to database and try to find this text by hash and equal deeper. Minus of such decision that it can be a **lot of texts** in database, so set will be a bit bigger=) 
May be your know how to solve it right?

Comment: If you used a cryptographically-secure hash, such as SHA256, you could skip the second step. It may be that the point of the question was to be sure you understood the point of a crytographically-secure hash.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't understand why I can skip second step if I will use SHA2? Could you explain me please)

Comment: Because that's the whole point of a cryptographically-secure hash function. The probability that two distinct inputs will have the same hash is orders of magnitude lower than the probability that your code to check for a duplicate will give a false positive due to a hardware defect.

Comment: I don't think this has something to do with cryptography directly. In my eyes it is about minimizing queries to the database. Hashing is a good start. However, you are right, it depends highly on the hashing function and collision probability.

Comment: @DNA It is a point, if we will store all hashes. But what is a variant - when it is not necessary to do it?

Comment: @xSNRG yes! I don't understand how to do this)

Comment: Please state what you mean by this "is this text in database or not".  Do you mean that "this text" is a complete match for one of the text documents in the database?  Or do you mean that one of the text documents *contains* the text?  These are different problems and have very different solutions.

Comment: @StephenC first one. I need only to know is the input text is one of the documents in db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the basic concept is to reduce the number of queries to the database by eliminating query texts that cannot possibly be in the database.

As you suggest, hashing is an excellent way to do this - if you use a good hash function (i.e. low probability of collision) then you would never need to actually compare the texts, since you would ([almost certainly](http://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities)) never get a false positive.

A variant of hashing (if memory becomes an issue) is to use a [Bloom Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter): "a space-efficient probabilistic data structure that is used to test whether an element is a member of a set." This approach uses far less memory than plain hashing, at the expense of some false positives (i.e. occasionally you would need to compare a text with the database to make sure whether you had a match). Bloom filters let you adjust the tradoff between memory and false positive rate. They are used in NoSQL databases such as [BigTable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigTable) and [Apache Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/).

**Update** as David Schwartz rightly points out, the hash function *does* matter, particularly in the case where a significant propertion of the queries *are* in the database - see our discussion in the comments below. Same issue applies to Bloom filters which are ideal when you want to narrow down your disk access to a small subset of files (for example) but not for eliminating disk/database access entirely, because of the false positives. I originally mentioned MurmurHash3 by way of a speed benchmark, but because it is non-cryptographic, it is unsuitable for this question. When I actually implemented approaches like this in the past, I used SHA1, which is cryptographic.

Comment: It is ok, but what if there are a lot of texts? where to store such a big number of hashes?

Comment: You could use a Bloom filter if space becomes a problem - will update answer.

Comment: If it to store in database -> expensive to go every time to database, if to store in program, it will be needed a lot of memory

Comment: If I were interviewing, I'd give this answer a B+. The point of the question was to minimize database access, but then you picked a hash that, while faster, requires more database accesses.

Comment: You've lost me there. I suggested a standard hashing approach that requires (probably) no DB accesses. The OP asked about an an approach that uses less memory, so I suggested Bloom filters, which are tunable to get an acceptable level of DB access (but still vastly lower than checking directly against the DB). Or do you mean that MurmurHash would give more collisions because it is not cryptographic? I suspect the difference would be negligible in a real application; in any case, I only quoted MurmurHash3 to give an concrete example of the speed that is possible, not as a recommendation.

Comment: @DNA: The difference is not negligible. Your approach will require a database access on every hit. An appropriate cryptographic approach will require no database accesses. The point of the question was to minimize database accesses. If 90% of the blocks you're checking for *are* in the database, your approach will hardly reduce database accesses at all.

Comment: @David Schwartz Ah, I see - you are quite right. For some reason I had been assuming that the vast majority of queries would be negative, which of course was unjustified (I have worked on systems where this assumption held, but here it does not!).